# Clip overlapping polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, clip

I do have an overlapping polygon shapefile of different radius. I want to clip a polyline for each fid individually. How is that possible in ArcGIS?

[image]

Comment: Check this https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm

Comment: All polygons are in one shapefile. and there are 8000 overlapping polygons in that shapefile. Is there any way I can clip the polyline row-wise?

Comment: thanks a lot. Yeah it does